# How to show a progressbar when do share?

Tags: android, popup, progress-bar

I write a program that can add a menu item in share menu. It can send the picture or others to some file server automatically.

How can I display a popup progressbar over the original view?

For example: in gallery choose a picture and touch share, it will display a popup menu includes "message, myshare, etc" items. The myshare is the program which i wrote. When I chose myshare it will send the picture to a special server. Meantime I want to display a progressbar to notify the sending progress. Now I can only display a empty activity only include a progressbar item. But it looks ugly. What I want to do is to display a popup progressbar over the Gallery view instead of a new acitvity. Can this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I totally understand what's going on.  BUT, if you already have an Activity working the way you want it to and your only issue is cosmetic, you should just style the Activity to look like a Dialog.  Take a look here:   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Basically, you'll be doing something like this:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

If it's not broken, don't fix it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you very much, SBerg413.